# Google Login via Selenium Python Not Working

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, firefox, selenium-chromedriver

Error: Couldn't sign you in
This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.

> 2FA is OFF and Less Secure Account is ON, already tried the same script with FireFox browser

`Chrome: 90.0.44` and `Python=3.9.5`

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WVDKZJkGlY'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=en')

# click sign in button
# driver.find_element_by_xpath(
#     '/html/body/ytd-app/div/div/ytd-masthead/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/ytd-button-renderer/a/tp-yt-paper-button').click()

# Email Field
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys('sagaryadav.careermaniaa@gmail.com')

# Next Button
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/button/div[2]').click()
sleep(1)

# Password Field
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys('Careermaniaa@SagarYadav1908')

# Login Button
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/button/div[2]').click()
```

Comment: What is the URL that you are using ? Please share code that you tried

Comment: @cruisepandey code is added

Comment: is chrome mandatory or you can switch to any browser ?

Comment: no, it is not mandatory. I can switch

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys(yourEmail)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="identifierNext"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="whsOnd zHQkBf"]').send_keys(yourPass)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="passwordNext"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Google is able to detect that your using a webdriver, you can use undetected_chromedriver to stop google from detecting you.